# Call R from Command Line on OSX

Tags: r, terminal, package, cran

I'm working with a program called msBayes that has a couple of R dependencies and, as far as I can tell, cannot access the necessary packages if I load them in either the GUI R interface or Rstudio.
I know that R can be called through the command line, but I'm very lost on how to install that capability. The exact version of R isn't critical, but if it's relevant, my OSX is 11.2 and the version of the GUI R I have is V4.1.0.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You can start an R console in the terminal by just typing `R`.
 Packages can be install by the command: `install.packages("MYPACKAGE")`.
 Also, packages can be directly install by the command `R -e "install.packages('MYPACKAGE')"`

Comment: Alright, thanks for that. I realized that I was trying to access R from inside a miniconda environment, and that was why the R command to call it wasn't working.